# Inserting empty arrays in JSON type fields in datastore

Tags: arrays, json, datastore, ckan

I have defined a field named "value" of type JSON (among some others fields) in a resource datastore. If I run upserts using simple values or not empty arrays all works ok:

```
POST http://host/api/3/action/datastore_upsert
{
   "resource_id": "...",
   "records": [
                 { "value": [ "1", "2" ] }
              ],
   "method": "insert",
   "force": "True"
}

POST http://host/api/3/action/datastore_upsert
{
   "resource_id": "...",
   "records": [
                 { "value": "23" }
              ],
   "method": "insert",
   "force": "True"
}
```

However, if I use an empty array

```
POST http://host/api/3/action/datastore_upsert
{
   "resource_id": "...",
   "records": [
                 { "value": [ ] }
              ],
   "method": "insert",
   "force": "True"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    ...
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "info": {
            "orig": [
                "malformed record literal: \"{}\"\nLINE 2:             VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '{}', NULL, to_t...\n                                                    ^\nDETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.\n"
            ]
        },
        "__type": "Validation Error",
        "data": "(DataError) malformed record literal: \"{}\"\nLINE 2:             VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '{}', NULL, to_t...\n                                                    ^\nDETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.\n"
    }
}
```

Given that `[ ]` is a valid element in JSON, I wonder why this error happens. Is it a known issue/bug in CKAN datastore API?

Comment: Created issue at https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/1776

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks! You have found a bug. I fixed it on https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/1776 and sent a pull request. This will be reviewed by another core dev and will be merged soon.

If you have some time, it would be useful if you could test that branch to confirm that it solves this issue. If you do so, please add a comment on the pull request.

Cheers!